# Moo tools errors out when including scripts in function.php - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mootools

My Moo Tools scripts error out when I place them into my functions.php, but work fine when I place them in my header.php

What works in the header.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://minnebyte.com/wp-  
content/themes/mb/js/mootools-1.2-more.js?ver=3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://minnebyte.com/wp-
content/themes/mb/js/mootools-fluid16-autoselect.js?ver=3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://minnebyte.com/wp- 
content/themes/mb/js/mootools-1.2.1-core.js?ver=3.5'></script>
```

What doesn't work in functions.php

```
// Basic Scripts
function MB_scripts()  
{  
wp_deregister_script('mootools-1.2-more');
wp_register_script('mootools-1.2-more', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-1.2-more.js');
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-1.2-more');

wp_deregister_script('mootools-fluid16-autoselect');
wp_register_script('mootools-fluid16-autoselect', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-fluid16-    
autoselect.js');
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-fluid16-autoselect');   

wp_deregister_script('mootools-1.2.1');
wp_register_script('mootools-1.2.1', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-1.2.1-core.js');
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-1.2.1'); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MB_scripts' );
```

Isn't it good practice to place them in the functions.php? 
[Tut](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

Link to
[My Page](http://minnebyte.com)

View in developer tools to see error

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it there but you should call your scripts on footer.php. It's a good practice to place your scripts at the bottom of your html document right before the closing body tag. You should also need to specify a dependency on your script. Those are the scripts that must be loaded before a certain script.

on your functions.php

```
wp_register_script('mootools-1.2-more', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-1.2-more.js');
wp_register_script('mootools-fluid16-autoselect', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-fluid16-
```

autoselect.js');
    wp_register_script('mootools-1.2.1', MB_PATH.'/js/mootools-1.2.1-core.js');

on your footer.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-1.2.1');
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-1.2-more', array('mootools-1.2.1'));
wp_enqueue_script('mootools-fluid16-autoselect', array('mootools-1.2-more'));
```

I'm not certain about the script order. Tweak as desired